# Package Operation failed on every installation

Tags: software-installation

I'm extremely new for the Ubuntu(Linux systems), my question is when I install any program in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ,its giving a message like below(sine times error is different but like this too).and also when I install software using terminal or software center ,the error is same like this..
although the error is occurred installed softwares are working properly please help me to solve this.

```
Error were encountered While Processing:
Samba
winbind
Error in function:
Setting up samba(2:4:1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3)..
smbd start/pre-start, process 1120
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d:initscript samba-ad-dc, action "start" failed
dpkg:error processing package samba(-configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg:dependency problems prevent configuration of winbind:
winbind depends on samba(=2:.4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu.14.04.3);however:
Package samba is not configured yet
dpkg: error processing package winbind (--configure):
dependency problems- leaving unconfigured
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

Comment: @Parto No this is not a duplicate. I don't even think it is a dependency issue.

Comment: @seth Looks like a dependency problem to me...

Comment: @Parto There is one dependency error, but that is only because samba failed to install. The real issue here is why samba failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you, by any chance, interrupt an install process? I think something like that might have caused it.

Try the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
```

This should reconfigure all your packages, but may take some time. I added the switch `-a` for all packages, since multiple packages seem to be causing issues. For more information about this command type the following command to see the manual page of the command:

```
man dpkg-reconfigure
```

Comment: I tried 2 time, but still the same error occurred.any thing else to do to resolve the problem?

Comment: You should follow the link in Parto's comment under your original question. Much better described than I could at this point.